# decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, HttpResponse found when using Render function in Django

Tags: python, html, django, typeerror, render

I'm trying to return a error page if a file is not found, by using the render shortcut after the FileNotFoundError and it doesn't work.

In view.py I have:

```
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "entry":util.get_entry(request, title)
        })
```

In util.py I have:

```
def get_entry(request, title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns error page.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        context = {}
        context['title_name']="Title name"
        return render(request,'encyclopedia/error.html',context,content_type='text/html')
       #return "The page '"+str(title)+"'"+" was not found."
```

I want to return a html page but it gives me this error
[Type error: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, HttpResponse found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW4Jl.png)

I'm a beginner and I'm really stuck on this code and I don't know how to change the type to a 'byte-like object'

Comment: why are you returning render if  FileNotFoundError

Comment: Basically, I want to return an error message but I wanted it to be formatted so I thought I could render a page.